# react router V6.4.3 useLoaderData

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm new to this and when I used V6.4.3 I found it updated to seem to authenticate using the loader, so I tried to simplify the original method. But when I use `useLoaderData()`, I get undefined.

**Index.js**

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
      <Route path="sign-in" element={<SignIn />} />    
      <Route path="/" element={<App />} errorElement={<LayoutError />}>
      <Route
        path="data"
        loader={() => { AuthProvider() }}
        element={<DataLayout />}
      />
      <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
      </Route>
    </>
));
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
  .render(
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
```

**AuthProvider.js**

```
export default function AuthProvider(){
  //{token: '4r8gjifendinsd'}
  const user = authService.getCurrentUser();
  //{"token":"asdasdasd"}
  console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
  if (!user.token) {
    throw redirect("/sign-in");
  }
  return user;
}
```

**DataLayout.js**

```
export default function DataLayout() {
  const user = useLoaderData();
  //undefined
  console.log(user);
}
```

I checked the official github example, Auth is still the legacy method, and then I checked the manual again carefully, just to make sure that `useLoaderData` receives JSON. Did I overlook something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only thing that appears out of place to me is the loader function not returning any value.

`loader={() => { AuthProvider() }}` should be:

- ```
  loader={() => {
    return AuthProvider();
  }}
  ```
- or more succinctly, `loader={() => AuthProvider()}`
- or even more succinctly `loader={AuthProvider}`

Example:

```
<Route
  path="data"
  loader={AuthProvider}
  element={<DataLayout/>}
/>
```